# What is the best place to store authentication token in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 as client?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I make a custom authentication system in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 project that send encrypted string as token to client and client store it in cookie and in every request I check that and make proper response.

Everything work great until user click on logout button; in this situation I mark the stored cookie as expired and client redirects to login page correctly, but if he clicks on browser back or types user panel in address bar, he can get back into a protected section again.

But if he refreshes the page for once, he couldn't get back to user panel without password and everything works well.

How can I fix this problem?

Or is there any better method to store token string safe in ASP.NET Core MVC clients?

Comment: You cannot fix that, that's browser history. You have to make the login button make a POST

Comment: Always bear in mind that you cannot control things on the client side and design/code accordingly.  And, that is all I have to say about authentication on the client.

Comment: so where can I store my custom cookie on client side and get it when I need?